# double con coma siempre C#

Tags: c#, double

Estoy capturando de un input en HTML que pasa a un string de `C#` asi:

```
string valor="12,5" o "15.5" //pueden ser valores con punto o coma
```

despues de tener el valor, reemplazo el punto con coma:

```
string nuevoValor = valor.Replace(".", ","); //salida: 15,5
```

Actualmente mi computadora tiene un `CurrentCulture` de `es-ES`, cuando trato de convertir el `string` a `double` pasa esto:

```
double valor1=Convert.ToDouble("15.5") //salida:155
double valor2=Convert.ToDouble("15,5") //salida:15.5 o aveces 15,5 no quiere depender de cuando le de la gana convertir a coma o no
```

Si aplico esto, si convierte de manera correcta:

```
double valor3= Double.Parse("15,5",NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); //salida: 15,5
```

Tengo que pasar la aplicacion que estoy haciendo a la computadora que la necesita, la cual tiene un `CurrentCulture` de `en-US`, lo cual no va a servir puesto que anteriormente habia utilizado `InvariantCulture` y me daba error tambien (según se `InvariantCulture` usa `en-US` como default)

Como puedo convertir un string que tenga punto o coma a double con coma sin importar que `CurrentCulture` tenga?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es sencillo simplemente usa la siguiente funcion:

```
public decimal TextoaDecimal(string s){
var clone = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
clone.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
clone.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
// ejemplo string s = "1,14535765" o string s="1.141516";
decimal d = decimal.Parse(s, clone);

return decimal;
}
```

saludos